# Pyo - How to Play two Sound Files read from RAM Sequentially?

Tags: python, pyo

I have two sound files of the same length that I want to play sequentially. Specifically, I want the first file to play three times, and the second file to play once.

I can achieve this through a `SfPlayer` and a `TrigFunc`, but I'm under the impression that this will read the sound file from disk each time I switch sounds. Is there a way I can accomplish this through a `SndTable`, [which holds the sounds in RAM](http://ajaxsoundstudio.com/pyodoc/examples/04-soundfiles/03-read-from-ram.html) ?

Here is the solution with using a `SfPlayer` and `TrigFunc`, [using this example as inspiration](http://ajaxsoundstudio.com/pyodoc/examples/04-soundfiles/02-read-from-disk-2.html).

```
from pyo import *
s = Server().boot()
DOWNLOADS = 'C:\\Users\\mmoisen\\Downloads\\'
first = DOWNLOADS + 'first.wav'
second = DOWNLOADS + 'second.wav'
sf = SfPlayer(first, speed=100/135.0, loop=True, mul=0.5).out()

count = 0

def foo():
    global count
    count += 1
    print count
    if count == 3:
        sf.path = second
    if count == 4:
        sf.path = forst
        count = 0

trig = TrigFunc(sf['trig'][0], foo)

s.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

To play sound files sequentially from RAM, I just needed to call `append` on the `SndTable`, like this:

```
from pyo import *
s = Server().boot()
DOWNLOADS = 'C:\\Users\\mmoisen\\Downloads\\'
first = DOWNLOADS + 'first.wav'
second = DOWNLOADS + 'second.wav'

# Using an array like this didn't work; it just played the first clip
# t = SndTable([first,first,first,second])
t = SndTable(first)
t.append(first)
t.append(first)
t.append(second)
a = Osc(table=t, freq=t.getRate(), mul=.4).out()

s.start()
```

Using a list of the sound files didn't work; it just played the first sound repeatedly.